# Regex to select numbers untill certain characters

Tags: regex

I have data with the following structure:

```
    abdc efgh  1234-5678\1
    abcd efgh 1234-5678
    abcd efgh 1234-5678 nmkl
```

I want to only select the number range 12345678 or only the numbers before the \ character, without the spaces and hyphens. So abcd efgh 1234-5678\1 would become 12345678.

I'm not that good with reg ex. Of course I tried [0-9], but I don't know how to escape the \ character.

Comment: Regex meta-characters are escaped using a backslash, so ```\\``` in your pattern will match a backslash in your input. If you can use capturing groups I'd match ```([0-9-]+)\\``` and retrieve your `1234-5678` from the first capturing group

Comment: I think it's a bit unclear if you'd either want to match any digit besides a 9 or if you want to capture the substring of numbers excluding the hyphen. Maybe you can be a bit more specific and update your question

Comment: If supported, you can match the numbers if they are not preceded by a backslash using `(?<!\\)[0-9]+` https://regex101.com/r/f5NZtA/1

Comment: Can't edit my comment anymore, but the regex is easy to modify to only retrieve the digits : ```([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\\``` and use the concatenation of the two capturing groups to get `12345678` ([try it here](https://regex101.com/r/wzm6sn/1))

Comment: @Aaron your solution didn't get rid of the \ character in the program that I use (FME, which is build with C++, I think?)

Comment: @JvdV I have edited my question

Comment: @Thefourthbird your solution does seem like it did the trick...!

Comment: @Minka my regex matches the backslash (and the dash too), but you're supposed to retrieve your result from its capturing groups. I don't know what environment you're running regex in, but for instance with [tag:sed] you would want to use `sed -n 's/.*([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\\.*/\1\2/p'` and with [tag:java] you'd want to use `matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2)`

Comment: @Aaron aah I see thank you for clarifying. Yes this seems like it should do the trick too.. Thank you

Comment: @Minka Can the string for example also be `12\123\245` ?

Answer (score 0):

To match all digits except for `\1` in the example data, you could use a negative lookbehind to assert what is directly to the left of the current location is not a backslash. Then match 1 or more digits.

```
(?<!\\)[0-9]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f5NZtA/1)